# UIbutton crashing app with no error other than (lldb)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am working on view A (createExerciseViewController) that adds view B (createRoutinePopupViewController) after clicking a UIButton.

This part works fine and the view is added fine.

Then inside view B (createRoutinePopupViewController) I have another UIButton. When I click this UIButton then the app crashes and all i get as an error is `(lldb)` and the NSLog is not executed.

but then sometimes and only sometimes it all gets executed fine after several crashes...

I am quite new to the iOS dev world and I have no idea what I could be doing wrong.

All UIButton method are `strong`

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

I think the issue could be in how i am inserting the subview and handling the whole subview??

A ---- createExerciseViewController.m

```
#import "createExerciseViewController.h"
#import "createExercisePopupViewController.h"
#import "createRoutinePopupViewController.h"

// ....more code

- (IBAction)createRoutine:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:[[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"createRoutinePopupView"] view]];
}
```

this is `UIViewController`
B ---- createRoutinePopupViewController.m

```
#import "createRoutinePopupViewController.h"
#import "createExerciseViewController.h"
#import "User.h"
#import "Routine.h"

- (IBAction)createRoutine:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Please dont crash");
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Try enabling exception breakpoints, and it should give you an error.  If you click on breakpoints on the top left under the play button.  The hit the + on the bottom and create a breakpoint for any exception

Comment: added the pic with the execution error but it doesnt say anything in particular. weirdly enough sometimes 1/10 times it executes the nslog

Comment: So the button is appropriately connected to that method, either via Interface Builder or with addTarget:action?

Comment: yup. the button is connected properly

Comment: Hmm, the code you have up there seems correct.  Not sure why it would only work 1/10 of the time

Comment: I think the issue is in how I add the subView because everything is well connected.

Comment: You could try below, I will add an answer with code.

Comment: You can't add a `UIViewController` as a subview. There is your first mistake.

Comment: @Popeye what should my subview be then?

Comment: If your wanting to show that `UIViewController` you need to do something like `presentModelViewController`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating view controllers just to add their views to another view controller's view willy-nilly. You need to tell the system that you're moving views from one controller to another, so that it can do its housekeeping. If you don't do this, one view controller ends up owning a view that's being presented by another view controller, so events and touches etc get confused. This *may* be what's causing the crash.

iOS now provides a 'container view controller' mechanism to manage this situation, whereby you tell the system that you're moving a view from one controller to another.

From [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html):

> The goal of implementing a container is to be able to add another view
>   controller’s view (and associated view hierarchy) as a subtree in your
>   container’s view hierarchy. The child remains responsible for its own
>   view hierarchy, save for where the container decides to place it
>   onscreen. When you add the child’s view, you need to ensure that
>   events continue to be distributed to both view controllers. You do
>   this by explicitly associating the new view controller as a child of
>   the container.

In practice, it's simpler than it sounds. Try something like this in createExerciseViewController.m:

```
    - (IBAction)createRoutine:(id)sender {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

        CreateRoutinePopupViewController* popupController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"createRoutinePopupView"];

        //Tell the operating system the CreateRoutine view controller
        //is becoming a child:
        [self addChildViewController:popupController];

        //add the target frame to self's view:
        [self.view addSubview:popupController.view];

        //Tell the operating system the view controller has moved:
        [popupController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
```

Comment: I like the reference to apple docs so I am not going to downvote but I have just tried your code and I can't get it to work. It gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: I got this working last minute. Typo from me. Ignore my last comment. +1.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    CreateRoutinePopupViewController *popUp = [[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"createRoutinePopupView"];
   [self presentModalViewController:popUp Animated:YES];
```

Comment: I want it to be a popup :( but regardless that says no visible @interface for createExerciseViewController declares the selector presentModalviewcontroller:animated

Comment: That is a view controller method so it should work.  Otherwise you can add popUp.view as a subview, rather than the controller itself

Comment: `presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated.

Comment: It was deprecated in `iOS 6` so if this is for anything below `iOS 6` it can still be used, but I would recommend `presentViewController:animated:completion:` as this was introduced in `iOS 5` to replace `presentModalViewController:animated:`